# Error in return type-Class

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am testing on return types using array and a class. But Somehow I am stuck while trying to return a class' object. In class notWhole, I tried to pass an array as an argument to the constructor but somehow compiler throws an error saying "field initializer can't initialize non static field member".

```
class Whole
{
    int[] Arr = new int[3];
    public Whole()
    {
    }
    public Whole(int[] arr)
    {
        Arr = arr;
    }

    public int[] Spit()
    {
        return Arr;
    }

}

class notWhole
{
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Whole w1 = new Whole(arr); //ERROR: can't pass an array(arr) as an argument
    public Whole wow()
    {
        return w1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that error message is enough to identify the reason, ie.,

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

So you can try like this:

```
Whole w1 = new Whole(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

or like this :

```
static int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Whole w1 = new Whole(arr);
```

Comment: U r damn lucky for me, the solution works, but can you plz explain, why didn't my version work right?

Comment: @SaurabhCooks: because You cannot use an instance variable to initialize another instance variable

Comment: How does using static help? Array is still a ref. variable which is being used to initialize a class.

Comment: @SaurabhCooks: since they are independent of instance

Comment: Do you know the reason for not using an instance variable to initialize another instance variable?

Comment: @SaurabhCooks:   Because the compiler can rearrange those variable, so there is no guarantee that variables will be initialized in the order of declaration, so they might throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear!

Comment: @SaurabhCooks: Mention not, Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

C# does not allow you to access in initializers section other fields or methods 
You could use a constructor for your purposes.
Also, if you use a static then you could create some side effects since all of your Whole instances will have a reference to same static array and a change in one of you Whole instance will be "available" in all others.

```
class notWhole
{
    Whole w1;
    public notWhole()
    {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        w1 = new Whole(arr); 
    }

    public Whole wow()
    {
        return w1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use Whole w1=new Whole(arr); within the constructor, complier throws an error, why?

Comment: Did you use Whole w1=new Whole(arr) or just w1 = new Whole(arr)? On first variant there might be a name conflict between local variable w1 and field w1

Comment: Or if your intent was just to return a new instance of Whole without keeping a reference to it then you don;t need w1 defined as field. Just instantiate  a new Whole variable in wow method and return it .